# Django: Digital Ocean django image gunicorn not using python venv

Tags: python, django

I have narrowed down a problem I have to this and I do not know how to solve it.

Gunicorn is not running in the venv...

Gunicorn script at /etc/init/gunicorn.conf...

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django

exec gunicorn \
    --name=project \
    --pythonpath=project \
    --bind=0.0.0.0:9000 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    project.wsgi:application
```

and then here is the gunicorn.py file reference in that file...

```
"""gunicorn WSGI server configuration."""
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from os import environ


def max_workers():
    return cpu_count() * 2 + 1

max_requests = 1000
worker_class = 'gevent'
workers = max_workers()
errorlog = '/var/log/gunicorn/error.log'
accesslog = '/var/log/gunicorn/access.log'
```

I have no idea where to go from here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that changing the exec line to

```
exec path/to/venv/bin/gunicorn
```

Is enough to activate the venv but then there were some dependencies which needed to be installed and logfile permissions which needed to be correct, I discovered everything by visiting /var/log/upstart/gunicorn.log